# How to get the filename and directory from a LLVM Instruction?

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-c++-api

I need to extract the directory and filename during a llvm pass. 
The current version of llvm moved `getFilename` and `getDirectory` from `DebugLoc` to `DebugInfoMetadata`. I can't find a class member `getFilename` directly in the `DebugLoc` header. Thus, how to do I go from an instruction to source code filename and directory?

http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1DebugLoc.html

Additionally, there is a print function that might help but it only takes a `llvm::raw_ostream` and can't be redirected to a `std::string`.

```
void print (raw_ostream &OS) const
// prints source location /path/to/file.exe:line:col @[inlined at]
```

The code below is what gives the error

```
const DebugLoc &location = an_instruction_iter->getDebugLoc()
StringRef File = location->getFilename() // Gives an error
```

---solution I figured out a few minutes ago----

```
const DebugLoc &location = i_iter->getDebugLoc();
const DILocation *test =location.get();
test->getFilename();`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)

```
std::string dbgInfo;
llvm::raw_string_ostream rso(dbgInfo);
location->print(rso);
std::sting dbgStr = rso.str()
```

2)

```
auto *Scope = cast<DIScope>(location->getScope());
std::string fileName = Scope->getFilename();
```

Comment: Second solutions works . First solution gives an error 

`no matching member function for call to 'print'
location->print(stream);`

Answer (score 4):

```
F.getParent()->getSourceFileName();
```

Where F is the function for which you want to get the source filename.